# Deleting an item from array by comparing array items

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input array:

**["temp/1/Lounge/empty", 
"temp/1/Lounge/66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,64,64,64,64…,64,64,64,64,64,64,64", "temp/2/Lounge/empty", 
"temp/3/Lounge/empty"]**

I have an array of elements as shown above.
Each item has four parts seperated by ('/').
If first three parts are same and fourth part is different for any two items.I want to remove the item having fourth part as 'empty'.

Example:
If fourth part of element has 'empty' in one item and some data like 66,64,…,64,64,64 in another element. 
I want to delete the item having 'empty' as fourth part in the array.

I want output as below:

**["temp/1/Lounge/66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,64,64,64,64…,64,64,64,64,64,64,64", 
"temp/2/Lounge/empty", 
"temp/3/Lounge/empty"]**

I tried to split the array items:

```
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   stringType = message.split('/')[0];
   day = message.split('/')[1] ; //day
   room = message.split('/')[2] ; 
   settingData = message.split('/')[3] ;
}
```

Please help me to compare items and delete from array.

Comment: put a working snippet, you question is too broad

Comment: Check the answer. I am sure that will be very useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

- first, store for every array value in a hash map what "4<sup>th</sup> values" it has;
- next, filter the array and explicitly delete array values of which the 4<sup>th</sup> value is *empty* and there are other 4<sup>th</sup> values (we can check this in the created hash map).

```js
function splitValue(value, ignoreCase) {
  let split = value.split('/'),
      key = split.slice(0, 3).join('/'),
      val = split.slice(3).join('/');
  if (ignoreCase) {
    key = key.toLowerCase();
  }
  return [key, val];
}

function filter(arr, ignoreCase = false) {
  var byKey = {};
  for (let value of arr) {
    let [key, val] = splitValue(value, ignoreCase);
    if (!byKey.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      byKey[key] = [];
    }
    if (val !== 'empty') {
      byKey[key].push(val);
    }
  }
  return arr.filter((value) => {
    let [key, val] = splitValue(value, ignoreCase);
    return (val !== 'empty' || byKey[key].length === 0);
  });
}

console.log(filter([
  "temp/1/Lounge/empty",
  "temp/1/Lounge/something",
  "temp/2/Lounge/empty",
  "temp/3/Lounge/empty"]));

console.log(filter([
  "temp/1/Lounge/something",
  "temp/3/kitchen/something",
  "temp/1/Lounge/empty",
  "temp/3/Kitchen/empty"]));

console.log(filter([
  "temp/1/Lounge/something",
  "temp/3/kitchen/something",
  "temp/1/Lounge/empty",
  "temp/3/Kitchen/empty"], true));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I also demonstrate in the above example how you can ignore casing of letters, so that `temp/3/kitchen/...` and `temp/3/Kitchen/...` are treated as belonging to the same group.

Comment: Hey thank you very much.this helped me. But if I have input like var arr = ["temp/1/Lounge/something",
"temp/3/kitchen/something",
"temp/1/Lounge/empty",
"temp/3/Kitchen/empty"].  I want output like this: var arr = ["temp/1/Lounge/something",
"temp/3/kitchen/something"]   how should I do?

Comment: The problem there is that `Kitchen` is different from `kitchen`, because of the capital `K` in one and lowercase `k` in the other. I updated my answer to address this and treat them the same.

Comment: This is what I wanted.Thank you very much for quick replay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It works perfectly what you need

```js
var resultData = ["temp/1/Lounge/empty", "temp/1/Lounge/66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,64,64,64,64…,64,64,64,64,64,64,64", "temp/2/Lounge/empty","temp/3/Lounge/empty"];
var data = resultData;
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
   var iItem = data[i];
   var iFirst = iItem.substring(0, iItem.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
   var iLast = iItem.substring(iItem.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, iItem.length);
   for(j=i+1 ; j<data.length; j++){
       var jItem = data[j];
       var jFirst = jItem.substring(0, jItem.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
       var jLast = jItem.substring(jItem.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, jItem.length);
       if(iFirst === jFirst && iLast==='empty'){
          resultData.splice(i,1);
       }
   }
}
console.log(resultData);
```

You can see that `data` array is exact copy of `resultData` array to maintain proper loop when you splice the element from them. For further work around and experimenting the long array values, here is the link to working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ehv2pvz8/1/)